# How to bake with self raising flour?

Tags: baking, flour, leavening

Is it possible to use self raising flour instead of all purpose and letting it raise with yeast? Also, is it necessary to add baking soda to self raising flour?

Comment: Do you mean replacing all purpose (plain) flour with self-raising flour in a bread recipe?

Answer (score 2):

Nope.. If you use self raising flour with yeast, the bread would come out like a cake..

Self raising flour already has baking powder added to it but if the recipe calls for self raising flour along with baking soda then add it...